# Gravity Equation - Velocity Equation | Why is it only good in certain FPS?

Tags: java, gravity

The jump size with these equations decreases as amount of updates per second goes down. With a delta value multiplying gravity force and amount that jumpspeed force decreases, as well as time elapsed being added by delta every iteration (the delta value is the amount of milliseconds passed since last update), one would think that it would work fine.

```
//d is delta
...
if(isFalling||isJumping){

        elapsedTime +=d;
//the elapsed time is the total amount of time passed since one started jumping,
//so that's logical to add the amount of time since last update.

        long tesquared = (long) Math.pow(elapsedTime, 2);
//amount of time elapsed squared.

        jumpSpeed+=-0.0000005*elapsedTime*d;
//this is the amount that jumpspeed is taken down by every time. 

        if(jumpSpeed > 0){
            isJumping = true;
        } else {
            isJumping = false;
        }
        double fGravity = 0.0000001*tesquared*d;

// this is the equation for gravity, the amount that the player goes down

        yRend += jumpSpeed - fGravity;
    //the amount it goes up, minus the amount it goes down.
        xRend -= strafeSpeed;
        oldyRend = yRend;

    }
```

To start a jump, one adds jumpSpeed by whatever amount.

The problem is that when the amount of updates per second decreases, the jumps decrease in duration and magnitute. I'm fairly certain that the delta values here are fine, which means that the problem must be in the equations themselves.

I'm thinking that `fGravity` is overrunning `jumpSpeed` more quickly when the delta is larger.

So my question. If the problem really is in the equations themselves, what is the correct way to model the upward force of a player minus the downward gravity force other than

`jumpSpeed+=-0.0000005*elapsedTime*d;`

and

`double fGravity = 0.0000001*tesquared*d;`?

If the problem is in the delta value not being applied correctly, then what would be the correct way to apply it?

Comment: I don't get how you've done it. vertical speed is normally the initial vertical speed minus gravity * timeElapsed. So how can jumpSpeed be decreased every frame by the timeElasped * delta ?
Your equations seem very wrong to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in essence asking what the right equations are. Would `fGravity` be applicable with the equation you described(placing it where `gravity` is), or is it also flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the equation of a jump are like that:

the gravity applies vertically and produce a constant force downward. So the vertical velocity is vy = vy0 - elapsedTime * g with g being the gravity constant and vy0 the initial velocity at the beginning of the jump.

You don't have to compute the elapsed time. Simply at every frame, you do this:

```
vy -= g * dt; // dt is the elapsed time since last frame

y += vy * dt;
x += vx * dt; // vx doesn't change in the jump
```

Comment: I assumed that the code you posted includes the vertical velocity you wrote in the paragraph above it. Are you certain that the delta value is only used in the line `vy -= g * dt`? It looks good, but the jump is still severely severed during low update amounts.

Comment: I am really sorry, I did a silly mistake in the update of x and y, forgot to multiply by dt there too. It shoud be much better now.

Answer (score 2):

Players do not have an "upward force" (except at the very point at which they're jumping).  Forces impart *momentum* generating *velocity*.  Once in the air, they do feel a *downward* force (i.e. gravity) which causes them to decelerate, ultimately generating a negative velocity which returns them to the ground.

If the player starts jumping upwards with velocity `u`, then at time `t` after the start of that jump the classic equation for calculating the position is `y = ut + 0.5 * at^2`.

In this case, `a` is gravity (which is negative, if `y` is "up"), giving `y = u * t - 0.5 * g * t ^ 2`